# Why is Android Handler parametized with int?

Tags: java, android, handler

I am really confused by the `android.os.Handler` mechanism in Android. Why does the [message handling](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#hasMessages%28int%29) use `int` to encode the type of message? After reading Effective Java, where I have learned to favor Enum over `int` for these kind of types, I feel very insecure how to proceed here.

I want to use the state pattern, defining different state classes which subclass from Handler in order to deal with different messages from the View.

```
public class ReadyState extends Handler {

     @Override
     public void handleMessage(Message msg, int what) {
          // ...      
     }
}
```

Do I have to encode my states with `int`, would one use an `Enum` with fields:

```
enum Action {
    START(0), STOP(1), BACKFLIP(2);

    int code;
    public Action(int code) { this.code = code }
}
```

Are there alternative approaches?

Comment: Android has no idea what enum you want to use.

Comment: Does the Handler class have a defined set of constants that you can use? for example Handler.THIS_MESSAGE_TYPE or Handler.THAT_MESSAGE_TYPE typically a class which is intended to use int arguments will define them as constants and this is the conventional way of passing them as arguments (even if they are just ints).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the message handling use int to encode the type of message?

It takes an int as a parameter because the authors of the library can't put *your* enum in there, they don't even know what it's called!

Comment: And that.  Since `Enum`s don't really `extend` very well, it would be kinda ugly.

Comment: And why didn't they use Generics then?

Comment: @MaxRhan Most likely because it would be overkill for this sort of application, all that is needed is a way to identify the message type.

Comment: It says, overkill is a word that is sometimes used as a substitute for not wanting to use a certain solution because it also solves other solution. Not that bad in my opinion, especially not if it is an integral part of the language.

Comment: Can i use Action.START.ordinal() ? it should be converted to int.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to map the `what` argument to an enum, that's the way to go.

Having it be an int means that you can use the argument as a bit set or a simple code or the actual data or whatever.

Comment: Instead of bit set it would be `EnumSet`. This seems very C-ish

Comment: @MaxRhan And so it is, but unless you want to make the `Handler` class abstract with an `Object` instead of an `int`, you gotta pick something to be the argument.

Comment: @MaxRhan  Also, the `Message` objects that `Handler`s pass around have to be easily serializable (trivially so, if possible) since they get used for interprocess communication.  And don't forget that the OS, below the Java layer is indeed written in C.